# how these real money earning app allow in play store? Why Not my?

Tags: google-play, google-developers-console

i got many time suspended in my developer account reason ***Money*** Keyword ***Cash*** Keyword
but how many of them app still publish and work properly with out any restriction in play store ?

example app 1[Play-Store-Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gameeapp.android.app)

[2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lucky.party.xingyunpaidui)

Comment: Same question i have how this real earning app publish ?

Comment: While it's a good question, Stack Overflow is not the appropriate forum for it.

Comment: where i post this question then?